# Pass input parameter to .click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function as follows:

```
      $("#submitBtn").on('click', function () {
          ....
      });
```

I am using the following in invoke the click it in a portion of code by doing:

```
     $('#submitBtn').click();
```

Is there a way to set a input parameter to the click.
For example, I need to pass a string value to the click so that the function can take appropriate steps. Note that the value of p is not from any element from the page. It is something I will be pro-grammatically setting based on some conditions.

```
     var p = 'sourceinfo';

     $('#submitBtn').click(p);
```

Comment: While it's possible to add data to the event (using [this method signature of `click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-eventData-handler)), it's generally considered better practice to read the information required from within the click handler itself.

Comment: On the case you proposed you don't actually need to send any parameters to your event. You just need to use a global variable and access it on your click handler. That way, whenever you need to change the value just change the variable and the event will handle it accordingly. It will probably require you to use an arrow function for your handler, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the event handler `.trigger()` instead of `.click()` 
**Syntax :**

```
.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters ] )
```

**Example:**

```
.trigger('click',[param1,param2])
```

After that you can get those params from your call back function after event param

Comment: How do I get the value of the input parameter from $("#submitBtn").on?

Comment: You have to reference the html element of the input param using Jquery example : $('#inputId').val() and pass it as an argument to the trigger param your function become like this $('#submitBtn').trigger('click',$('#inputId').val()); dont forget to change the input id

Answer (score 1):

Alright, the best way to do this is by adding custom data-attribute `params` to the element before chaining it with the `click` event:

```
$("#submitBtn").data("params", {
    one: "Parameter 1",
    two: "Parameter 2"
}).click();
```

And you can use params like this:

```
$("#submitBtn").on('click', function () {

    // Parameter 1
    alert( $(this).data("params").one );

    // Parameter 2
    alert( $(this).data("params").two );

    // Do other stuff

});
```

Check [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5hLz8xsm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Click is a event generated and cannot pass the message/data. Instead you can pass the args to the listener(calling method).so that it can be captured to that method.
for e.g

```
<button onclick="handleClick('msg',event)"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.trigger()` instead.

```
$('#submitBtn').trigger('click', [arg1, ...]);
```

You can retrieve the parameters passed when attaching the click handler

```
$('#submitBtn').on('click', function(e, arg1, ...) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you jQuery(this).attr('action') ... Inside the function
And on the element add attribute as follow data-action('myaction')